# Size of L1 cache memory on T9600 CPU

Tags: parallel-processing

I want to know the size of the l1 cache memory for my processor T9600
I visited Intel website for the specification of the processor but couldn't get the needed information.
 
Any one help me
thank you ^_^

Comment: This post should probably be moved to SuperUser as it is not programming related.

Comment: Took the liberty to edit, including  `CASH` --> `CACHE` ;-)  ' been looking for money inside them CPU chips but found none so far (minute amounts of gold, however)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you ever wanted to know about your CPU/motherboard/RAM hardware can be learned from [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php).

Comment: Dang, beat me to it... ;)

Comment: CPU-Z is Windows-only though.

Answer (score 0):

> 32 KB instruction L1 memory cache and
>   32 KB data L1 memory cache for each
>   core.

From: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/366

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/ion/PSREF/PENRYN.pdf

> L1 cache - 64KB per core split between
>   data cache (32KB) and instuction cache
>   (32KB)
>
> L1 data cache - 2x32KB data cache,
>   integrated
>
> L1 instruction cache - 2x32KB
>   instruction cache, integrated